# How to ignore Null values in Post request body in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am calling a REST service with POST verb. Post request body is constructed dynamically.In some cases few fields will be populated with null values.Even though I used my Request pojo with `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` or `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` null value fields are not getting removed.

My sample request will be looks like below.

I am constructing requestEntity by myself and not parsing it before posting.

```
resetTemplate.exchange(uri,HTTP.POST,requestEntity,responseObject)
```

How do I remover in the request body fileds with null value

I am using **Spring Boot 1.5.9** and it uses **Jackson 2.x**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` should have worked for you!

You seem to be constructing the request entity by yourself and not sure if you are passing on a JSON string with NON_NULL. Try this instead directly with entity if you have annotated with Jackson annotations.

```
restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, requestDto, ResponseDto.class);
```

Comment: I am constructing RequestEntity my self not parsing

Comment: @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) should work removing the empty values on post request to other service, even when constructing the new entity and setting values by yourself

Comment: This worked for me, although I had to specify `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

Just use this `@JsonSerialize(include = Inclusion.NON_NULL)` instead of `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` and it works..!!

NOTE :`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize.Inclusion` is now deprecated.